# Data from Rows to a Single Column? (Cell Formula)

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a way to convert data from a row-array over to a single column, without breaks, using cell formulas?

**Example Table:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following explanation does what you are looking for, EXCEPT it also includes the empty (unanswered) questions. I can't think of a way to do also remove the empty ones.

source: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2775-excel-convert-matrix-to-single-column.html

Another way would be to use VBA

Comment: I can work with this - thank you so much!